# append' produces '()', not the expected contextual result type 'String

Tags: ios, swift

I was making an app that would encode messages using regular ciphers that could be decoded on paper, and I ran into this problem. [Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUyTT.png)

I'm not sure if you need it, but here is the code it is inside:

```
func encodeMessage(input:String) -> String {
    var output:String
    if  cipher == "Ceaser/Shift" {
        for i in 0..<input.characters.count {
            output = output.append(alphabet[seekAlphabet(letter: input[i])])
        }
    return output
    }
}
```

Another piece of code that might help:

```
func seekAlphabet(letter:String) -> Int {
    for i in 0..<alphabet.count {
        if alphabet[i] == letter {
            return i
        }
    }
}
```

alphabet is just an array that is the alphabet in a series of strings.

Any ideas of why it is doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you lookup the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string)? `append` *appends* to the given string. It does not return a value.

Comment: In general it would be helpful to include the full error message into the body of the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift `String` class `append(_:)` is mutating function and doesn't return anything. Change this line

```
output = output.append(alphabet[seekAlphabet(letter: input[i])])
```

to

```
output.append(alphabet[seekAlphabet(letter: input[i])])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this very much helped my code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on this line:

```
output = output.append(alphabet[seekAlphabet(letter: input[i])])
```

The append instance method mutates the original string, it does not return a value with the result. If you would have looked over the **[docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641225-append)**, you would have seen that it is declared as:

```
mutating func append(_ other: String)
```

---

Here you have two ways to solve this, by replacing

```
output = output.append(alphabet[seekAlphabet(letter: input[i])])
```

with either of the following:

- `output.append(alphabet[seekAlphabet(letter: input[i])])`
- `output = output + alphabet[seekAlphabet(letter: input[i])]`

---

### Why was that assignment illegal?

Now, you know that `append(_:)` is a mutating function, and

```
output.append(alphabet[seekAlphabet(letter: input[i])])
```

is a `()` (a `Void`), because it just mutates and does not return anything. Therefore, by trying to assign `output` to the `append(_:)` method, you try to assign a string to a `Void`, which is illegal.

Comment: This also answered my question but I saw the other one first. I am new to programming and haven't looked over the docs much.  Sorry for being too hasty!